# Place ImageButton in the center of ImageView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can I adjust the `imageButton` in the center of `ImageView`?

Below are the code I have tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:background="@color/darkpurple"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <Button
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:background="@color/darkpurple"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:background="@drawable/camera"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonOne"
        android:paddingTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="67dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/comments"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/comments" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Date"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Date"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:hint="Date"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Amount"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Amount"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:hint="Amount"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Comments"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Comments"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amount" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_edittext"
        android:hint="Comments"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Comments"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

My ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: use imageview and button in linear layout and set gravity in center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use code, it works for all screen size(Please replace image with yours[image]):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <Button
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<ImageView
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonOne"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Date"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Date"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Date"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:hint="Date"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Amount"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Amount"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/Amount"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/amount"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:hint="Amount"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:id="@+id/Comments"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:text="Comments"
    android:layout_below="@+id/amount" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="290dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:paddingBottom="80dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="13dp"
    android:id="@+id/comments"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:hint="Comments"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Comments"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<FrameLayout android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_width="200dp"                
    android:background="@color/light_gray"         
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="65dp"
    android:background="@drawable/camera"
    android:layout_height="55dp"                 
    android:id="@+id/imageButtonOne"
    android:layout_gravity = "center"                
   />
</FrameLayout>
```

Check it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is simple, make changes according to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

  <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="250dp"
   android:layout_height="250dp"  >

   <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/base"
       android:layout_height="250dp"
       android:layout_width="250dp"
       android:src="@drawable/home"
       android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ImageButton
       android:id="@+id/center"
       android:layout_height="150dp"
       android:layout_width="150dp"   
       android:src="@drawable/home"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"   />
 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In order to move it to the top right corner, you can specify

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
```

to the Relative Layout with fixed widths, This places the Layout at the top right corner, then you can add margins to keep at a position where you require.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @Seng From what I read, you are trying to place an image button in middle of an ImageView , am I right?

Comment: That's what it does, it creates a nested Relative layout, and creates the imageView consuming the entire space of that relative layout, and then places the imagebutton in middle of the relative layout, the result is what you asked in the question

Comment: @Seng checkout answer, i posted now

Answer (score 1):

Past this as it is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
        android:background="@color/darkpurple"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <Button
            android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:background="@color/darkpurple"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlImages"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@color/light_gray" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonOne"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@drawable/add_tag" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/rlImages"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Date"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Date"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Date"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:hint="Date"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Amount"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Amount"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:hint="Amount"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/Comments"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:text="Comments"
        android:layout_below="@+id/amount" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:paddingBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="13dp"
        android:id="@+id/comments"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:background="@drawable/roundedcorner_edittext"
        android:hint="Comments"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Comments"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You need to use RelativeLayout with the use of

```
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:layout_centerVertical="true"
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout with that

```
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView  
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 

            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/img" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"

            android:padding="12dip"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:text="Button" />

    </FrameLayout>
```